# Maven: Project build error 'modelVersion' is missing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to create a new Maven project but I get this error from the pom.xml...

Can anybody help me solving the problem, please? I'm a completely newbie with Maven & Eclipse IDE

Thank you so much.

[image: Error details]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your `pom.xml` is incomplete

you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>your-version</version>

<!-- all stuff here -->

</project>
```